# How to order a result set by a field with multiple values?

Tags: solr, lucene, solr-query-syntax, solr-multy-valued-fields

In my SOLR I keep events that repeats themselves.
So, event A has something a repeat on the 11th 12th and 29th
Event b has repeat on the 2nd and 15th
Event c has on the 12th and 29th

I want to fetch the events ordered by their dates, I want it to be ordered by the first date in the collection.
Expected result:

```
Event B  
      A
      C
```

The schema entry is

```
 <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

 <field name="date_start" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

What would bethe URL I would use?

Answer (score 1):

My solution, which googeling suggest to be the only simple one, is to copy the first date into a separate sortable field.

Comment: That's the only possible way. Starting with SOLR 3.x, sorting on multivalued fields throws an exception. With 1.x (particularly 1.4) it works, although the sorting may or may not be effective. I tried with copyfields, but you cannot copy from multivalue to single value

Comment: I do the copy in my app, before I populate (insert) into SOLR